# Acumatica - Create time cards using the API

Tags: api, rest, acumatica, card

I have successfully created Time Activities with the Rest API but now my customer wants to see those activities associated in a Time Card. I have been looking at the documentation but I haven't found how to create a time card and then associate activities to it.

Thanks

Comment: Have the time activities been approved?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create your own end-point object of the screen on the same Web Service End-Point you call. I would suggest running all the activities and then create a timecard associated with the employee, the activities will then pull through based on the date of the activity within the period of the timecard.